# How to handle alternate views within a scene

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am making modifications to an existing iPad application, and I'm having a hard time dealing with really messy scenes in storyboards.  Almost every scene in the app consists of multiple views laid one on top of the other, each containing a different set of controls.  Depending on the situation or data coming into the scene, some views are hidden, and others are shown.

It takes a LOT of time to decipher such scenes, and even when I figure out what changes I need to make it's terribly difficult to make those changes, and easy to screw up other things.

As an example, the following scene has 3 views that could appear (Start View, End View, Drawer History), depending on the situation, and they are all laid out on top of each other...

[image]
[image: Overlaid views in a scene]

This *seems* like a terrible way to handle this, and I'm having a hard time believing this is standard practice, but I'm not finding much in the way of alternatives.  I find very little in the way of questions where people are dealing with this problem, and the tutorials on how to design user interfaces seem to be too simplistic and never deal with scenes that are complex enough to run into this problem.

Unfortunately, this app is my primary introduction to doing user interfaces in iOS, so it has apparently become the default solution in my head.  I've tried many tutorials, but they take a long time and don't seem to ever get to a situation that needs such a technique to solve it.

I would hope there would be a solution where each alternate view in the scene could be laid out on its own, and be made to appear within a placeholder view as needed.

What would be a more enlightened / more manageable approach?

Comment: Since asking, I have found 2 possible improvements...  "Secondary Views" and "Embedded view controllers", which may be appropriate for different situations...  Will follow up if I'm able to make these techniques work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you'll get with Storyboards/Nibs/Xibs. I'm not saying coding your UI is better than using interface builder, but it is, at least for me. I believe, as far as I know, there's no other way to handle such multiple layers of views in one view controller in interface builder. I actually used to use interface builder before and that's how I add multiple layers of controls too. Sometimes some views are initially made hidden, but that would probably confused me or the other developer looking at the layout. Sometimes I extend the viewcontroller height to know that there's a view container with a constraint a thousand constant or a negative thousand constant to make it hidden and ready to animate when it's needed to be shown.

There are ways to somehow improve and organize your Storyboards. You can separate modules into different storyboard files; you can use references; avoid segues; and whatnot. It's still an individual or team's preferences.

Some ref:

https://cocoacasts.com/organizing-storyboards-with-storyboard-references

https://medium.com/@stasost/xcode-a-better-way-to-deal-with-storyboards-8b6a8b504c06

EDIT:

I'm thinking you could also layout separate view containers into a separate xibs, and then call them or layout them when needed. But that would add more files to your project.